# Magento 2 : Redirect in case it's not me during dev phase

Tags: magento2, redirect, development, testing

I've already installed Magento 2 and started with config and uploading products - working quite nice.

Now I'd like to forward all traffic to another website (currently just using a index.php with a simple http redirect) UNLESS it is me.

Maybe more a PHP topic then Magento but maybe there is sth in Magento that can help?

So basically: 
If me show me Magento etc. as usualy
else redirect

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish by simply adding this to `.htaccess` located on your magento's root;

```
<RequireAll>
    Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx yy.yy.yy.yy
</RequireAll>
```

Repalace all xx with IPs to be allowed separated with spaces.

Comment: Good hint. I was kind of avoiding the IP route since I don't have a static IP - but it's working now. I had to adjust the solution though, I'm running on NGINX - sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Vivek Kumars answer, it's possible to do it via IP. That solution would be more convenient for people with a static IP, but it's working smoothly.

For **NGINX**:

```
location / {
error_page 403 = @deny; // or just return a file
allow 127.0.0.1;
deny all;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location @deny {
return 301 http://example.com/comingsoon;
}
```

I used **PHP** now inside the **index.php** at the very beginning - not pretty but it works.

```
// Check DEV:
check_for_dev_ip();
function check_for_dev_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    $allowedIP = '123.123.';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';


    if (strpos($ipaddress, $allowedIP) !== false) {
        // Do nothing, process Magento
    }
    else
    {
        include ( "header-redirect.php" );
        exit;
    }
}
// END Check DEV
```

**header-redirect.php** would be a simple html barebone with:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://your_url'" />
```